# JQuery buttonset("refresh") fails after the second time with radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button, refresh

I use the following Jquery buttonset within my Project:

```
<div id="TR1_Mode">
    <input type="radio" id="TR1_Mode_Dif" name="TR1_Mode_radio" value="Mode_Dif" ><label for="TR1_Mode_Dif">Differentiation</label>
    <input type="radio" id="TR1_Mode_Int" name="TR1_Mode_radio" value="Mode_Int" checked="checked"><label for="TR1_Mode_Int">Integration</label>
</div>
```

Changing the "checked" states programatically with the following code (tried in the console):

```
$('[name="TR1_Mode_radio"][value="Mode_Dif"]').attr("checked", false);
$('[name="TR1_Mode_radio"][value="Mode_Int"]').attr("checked", true);
$('#TR1_Mode').buttonset("refresh");
```

It may work, but after doing the same thing in reverse:

```
$('[name="TR1_Mode_radio"][value="Mode_Dif"]').attr("checked", true);
$('[name="TR1_Mode_radio"][value="Mode_Int"]').attr("checked", false);
$('#TR1_Mode').buttonset("refresh");
```

The checked button will becomme unchecked, but the unchecked will not become checked. Am I missing something or is this a misbehaviour in jquery?

Checkbuttons seem to behave well, but they do not fullfill the same purpose.

I treid this using Chrome (32.0.1700.107 m) and Firefox (27.0.1), and tested it with the latest Jquery versions: jquery-2.0.3.js and jquery-1.10.2.js

Comment: try $('[name="TR1_Mode_radio"][value="Mode_Int"]').removeAttr("checked") instead of attr("checked", false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between `$.prop` and `$.attr`.  Specifically, attr is equivalent to re-writing the html, while `prop` actually modifies the value of the DOM object.  So, this would work:

```
$('[name="TR1_Mode_radio"][value="Mode_Dif"]').prop("checked", true);
$('[name="TR1_Mode_radio"][value="Mode_Int"]').prop("checked", false);
```

or this would work

```
$('[name="TR1_Mode_radio"][value="Mode_Dif"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
$('[name="TR1_Mode_radio"][value="Mode_Int"]').removeAttr('checked');
```

Examples you find online can be confusing because older versions of jQuery (<1.6) only had a single `attr` method that would behave somewhat inconsistently between these two behaviors.

For what its worth, I personally find `prop` leads to more expressive and understandable code.

Comment: Great, Matt! Thanks a lot this works very fine (just tried the "prop"s as I like this style more). I miss documentation about things like that - how to retrieve values from controls and also set them again. Normally I would expect that to be found in the API of a control but these are very slim regarding this. Do you have any hints for me regarding this kind of info? Many Thanks :-) and Thumbs up!

Comment: Sometimes learning from courses like codeacademy.com might be useful. If this answer satisfies you, please accept it.